# Find the min number in all contiguous subarrays of size L of a array of size n

Tags: algorithm

The minimum number in a subarray of size L. I have to find it for all the subarrays of the array. Is there any other way than scanning through all the subarrays individually?

I have one solution in mind:

```
a[n]//the array
minimum[n-l+1]//the array to store the minimum numbers

minpos=position_minimum_in_subarray(a,0,l-1);
minimum[0]=a[minpos];
for(i=1;i<=n-l-1;i++)
{
    if(minpos=i-1)
    {
        minpos=position_minimum_in_subarray(a,i,i+l-1);
    }
    else {
        if(a[minpos]>a[i+l-1]) minpos=i+l-1;
        minimum=a[minpos];
    }
}
```

Is there any better solution than this?

Comment: Is this a homework or interview question?

Comment: And what do you mean by min number?  The minimal sum of `l` adjacent numbers in array `n`?

Comment: By min I mean the minimum number in the sub array.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12239042/1088243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a double ended queue(Q) .Find a way such that the smallest element always appears at the front of the Q and the size of Q never exceeds L. Thus you are always inserting and deleting elements at most once making the solution O(n). I feel this is enough hint to get you going.

Comment: My approach and implementation of this algorithm can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12239580/1088243

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is OK , but to work properly it should be something like :

```
a[n]//the array
minimum[n-l+1]//fixed

minpos=position_minimum_in_subarray(a,0,l-1);
minimum[0]=a[minpos];
for(i=1;i<=n-l-1;i++)
{
    if(minpos=i-1)        
        minpos=position_minimum_in_subarray(a,i,i+l-1);                   
    else if(a[minpos]>a[i+l-1]) //fixed
        minpos=i+l-1; //fixed

    minimum[i] = a[minpos];
}

// Complexity Analysis :

//Time - O(n^2) in worse case(array is sorted) we will run
         "position_minimum_in_subarray" on each iteration

//Space - O(1) - "minimum array" is required for store the result
```

---

If you want to improve your time complexity, you can do it with additional space.
For example you can store each sub array in some self-balancing BST (e.g. red-black tree) and fetch minimum on each iteration :

```
for (int i= 0; i<n; i++) {
    bst.add(a[i]);

    if (bst.length == l) {
        minimum[i-l] = bst.min;
        bst.remove(a[i - l]);            
    }
  }

 //It's still not O(n) but close.

 //Complexity Analysis :

 //Time - O(n*log(l)) = O(n*log(n)) - insert/remove in self-balancing tree
                                      is proportional to the height of tree (log)

 //Space - O(l) = O(n)
```

Comment: The question has been edited with the fixes you suggested but is there a better solution.

Comment: What do you want to improve ? see complexity analysis in my answer.

Comment: I would like to improve the complexity get it to O(n).

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it in `O(n)`. See my answer with `O(nlogn)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Scala version answer

```
def movingMin(windowSize: Int, array: Seq[Double]) = { 
    (1 to array.length - (windowSize - 1)).
        map{i => (array.take(i + (windowSize - 1)).takeRight(windowSize)).min}
}
```